# how to set sync for AJAX which open a JSP when success

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a button and it's click event is like below.

```
var option={id:"TextBox2,TextBox3",column:"0,2"};
jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/SAP_SD_QUERY/Query.jsp',   
      success: function(data) {
             window.open("/SAP_SD_QUERY/Query.jsp?" + $.param(option));
                 }
});
```

It will open a JSP query page and fill selected value to textbox in the page. The code is below.

```
close.window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("openWinBody");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var selected;
    for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
         var row = table.rows[i];
         var chkbox = row.cells[9].childNodes[0];
         if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            selected=i;
            }
        }
      var t1="<%= filter%>".split(",");//the parameter id
      var t2="<%= filter_t%>".split(",");//the parameter column
      if (t1.length>0)
              {
              for (var j=0;j<t1.length;j++){
                window.opener.document.getElementById(t1[j]).value = 
              table.rows[selected].cells[t2[j]].innerHTML;
            }            
     };
```

I test it and it work for the first time button click, but when second time click it didn't. The query page opened but returned value not displayed.But when I debug the page the return result is correct. I doubt it may relevant to the Sync/Async mechanism. But if I add sync:false to the AJAX, it return nothing. So what's the correct way to do it?Thx.